# Does printer drivers can be installed to just any kind of printer?

Tags: drivers, printer

Does printer drivers can be installed to just any kind of printer ?

Comment: What do you mean by "installed to" a printer? Printer drivers are installed on a computer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Printer drivers are designed to work with the printers they are written for, but a small handful of drivers will be able to power a large number of printers - although not necessarily take full advantage of them - for example PCL6 will work for most laser printers.